# Bevel the edges of a cube and then add new face to the top face of the cube breaks the topology

Tags: workflow, topology, bevel

In Blender 4.0.2, on the default cube, if I want to add a face using the Inset Faces tool in Edit Mode on the top face of the cube, then select two edges of the cube and bevel them, I get a nice topology like this:

[image]

But if I first select the two edges and bevel them (with 20 segments) and then select the top face and add new face using the Inset Faces tool, I get this mess:

[image]

My question is: is it necessary to always add a face first and then bevel the edges? Or is there a workaround, and can I add faces cleanly on objects that are already beveled?

PS: I tried to apply a modifier to the cube, but it beveled all the edges and I want just two of them to be beveled.

Comment: In Blender the order of your actions are very important. And it doesn't matter if it is sculpting, editing vertices, order of modifiers....the result will be different in nearly all cases. So yes, you should bevel at last (in normal cases)

Comment: That's how I'd expect it to work. One thing I'd say is that you should use far fewer segments on your bevel, maybe 4 or 5, and then right-click > Shade Smooth in Object mode to smooth the bevel.

Comment: in this case, instead of inseting the face, you can use E to extrude, right click to leave the face in place, then scale it down with S. You wont have any overlapping issue that way

Comment: @Alex You might only have to change the pivot point then, because the default _Median_ will scale the face more towards the beveled edges instead of the center of the orginal face before beveling.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yes, I forgot to mention that. Bounding box pivot point should work in this case

Comment: @Alex Yep, in this case it would. Also with a square face you can scale and the distance from the outer edges will be even in X and Y direction like an inset. With a non-square  face of course not.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it isn't really a topology difference, the mesh itself is very different. If you inset the face before the bevel, the face on the top of the cube will have only four vertices. When you inset after the bevel, the face on the top has to deal with the extra vertices on the bottom two corners due to the added bevel. You should decide on whether you want to deal with the extra vertices on the top face depending on the final look you want to achieve.